# How can I use grep with variable and wildcard?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep

How can I handle both wildcard and variables in grep?
My goal is to grep anything that matches "string*", and my string is $i.
I've tried many options and nothing works:

```
max="$(nc resources | grep "$i*" | awk '{print $3}')"
available="$(nc resources | grep "$i*" | awk '{print $7}')"

max="$(nc resources | grep '$i*' | awk '{print $3}')"
available="$(nc resources | grep '$i*' | awk '{print $7}')"
```

also fgrep, grep with flags etc.
thank you.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Globs does not expand inside quotes, regardless if it is single or not.

Answer (score 0):

`string*` matches stringggggg. You probably want to match `string.*`

You can concatenat strings by putting them next to each other.

`max="$(nc resources | grep "$i"".*" | awk '{print $3}')"`

is equivalent to

`max="$(nc resources | grep "$i" | awk '{print $3}')"`

So i suppose you would want the second one.